# Communicating between Fragment and Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, interface

I have a fragment with multiple toggle buttons. On click of a particular button in my Activity, I'd like to upload the status of all these toggle buttons to the server. I see there is one way of doing it as explained in the below link, where we create a listener interface and on every click of each toggle button, we update some tag/integer in the activity corresponding to each toggle button.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

But I would like to know if there is any way to know the checked/unchecked status of all toggle buttons in the fragment from the activity without implementing the interface methods for each time a toggle button is clicked. Hope I'm clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example of how to achieve that. The activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ToggleFragment toggleFragment;
    Button updateStatusButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        updateStatusButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateStatusButton);

        toggleFragment = ToggleFragment.newInstance();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.main_frame, toggleFragment, "ToggleFragment")
                                    .commit();

        updateStatusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean buttonsChecked = toggleFragment.areToggleButtonsChecked();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.format("Toggle buttons checked: %s", buttonsChecked), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the Fragment:

```
public class ToggleFragment extends Fragment {
    ToggleButton toggleButton1;
    ToggleButton toggleButton2;
    ToggleButton toggleButton3;

    public static ToggleFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        ToggleFragment fragment = new ToggleFragment();

        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toggle_fragment, container, false);

        toggleButton1 = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        toggleButton2 = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
        toggleButton3 = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);

        return view;
    }

    public boolean areToggleButtonsChecked() {
        return toggleButton1.isChecked()
                && toggleButton2.isChecked()
                && toggleButton3.isChecked();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it even possible to call " toggleFragment.toggleButton1.isChecked() " in activity? Even if we make Buttons public in fragment, I don't think this will work. I just verified and that didn't work. Am I missing something in how you're instantiating toggleFragment from activity

Comment: With regard to your second suggestion, how do I call this function from activity. That is where I want the boolean returned

Comment: I just edited the answer with a working example, tested it on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the best way that you could accomplish this is with a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) from the Android Architecture Components library. The `ViewModel` can have an `ObservableField` or `LiveData` value that each of the Fragments can observe, and always have the correct information. This would also make it easier to be lifecycle-aware.